# Best structure for initial set views of Ember application

Tags: ember.js

I'm currently working on an application which uses Ember.js, however I am having problems finding the correct way to set the context for my route view.

For the initial view of my application, I need to make 3 AJAX requests (1. basic user details, 2. user address, 3. user images).

At the moment I have these set up as 3 separate functions on a user object - then a single functions which calls all 3 and returns an object - combining the results of all 3.

This works for the most part, however sometimes my route view tries to render before the AJAX requests have completed and therefore causes errors in my view.

Any ideas how to better structure this and resolve my issue?

Comment: Create a property in your controller that is false when ajax is loading data, and when all the data is loaded you set this property to true; then in your templates you can add and `{{if }}` to check this property and only display your views once it's done loading. Check [this controller](https://github.com/MilkyWayJoe/hello-ember-router/blob/master/HelloEmberRouter/Scripts/app.js#L120-158) and [this template](https://github.com/MilkyWayJoe/hello-ember-router/blob/master/HelloEmberRouter/Views/Home/Index.cshtml#L53-67) to see how it can be done. (Sorry this code is OLD, but you get the idea)

Comment: In that controller, check for the ajax call and look at the `complete` callback